# Application Request Routing - Single server webfarm setup in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, reverse-proxy, web-farm, arr

I'm trying to setup Application Request Routing (v2.5) on my Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.5.

So far I got this:

1. IIS 7.5 running two sites

   - `www.domain1.com`
   - `test.domain1.com`
2. IIS 7.5 with a webfarm called **My-Farm** with one server: `test.domain1.com`
3. Apache Tomcat running some server on `www.domain1.com:10000`

I'm able to route requests coming to `www.domain1.com` to the webfarm but I don't see any result coming from `test.domain1.com`?

I also tried changing servers at step 2 above to `localhost` or `www.domain1.com:10000` or `localhost:10000` but whatever I do the requests aren't proxied.

**Am I setting ARR up correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

In ARR, when hosting the sites locally in the same server as ARR, I tend to split the public facing sites (receiving the requests) from the proxied sites.

In your case your could have something like this:

```
IIS:
   - Site 1 (binding: test.domain1.com:80)
   - Site 2 - proxied (binding: 127.0.0.1:22001)

Rewrite Rule
  - Match All
    - {HTTP_HOST} matches test.domain1.com
    - {SERVER_PORT} does not match 22001
  - Action: Route to Far
```

This way, requests arriving to Site 1 are routed to Site 2 when requesting test.domain1.com. The port change and the rule avoid ARR routing requests to site 2 again.